# How to add results of Levenshtein method as a column to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, levenshtein-distance

I want to add the results calculated by the Levenshtein method to an existing dataframe.
The calculation for the Levenshtein distances looks as follow:

```
#define arrays
a = df.a.to_numpy()
b = df.b.to_numpy()

#calculate Levenshtein distance between two arrays
for i,k in zip(a, b):
  lev_distance_a_b = (lev.distance(i, k))
  print(lev.distance(i, k))

#Output
6
4
5
5

#Add output to existing dataframe and print dataframe:

#df['a_b'] = lev_distance_a_b
#print(df)
```

| a | b | a_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mavs | Rockets | 5 |
| Spurs | Pacers | 5 |
| Lakers | Warriors | 5 |
| Cavs | Celtics | 5 |

This is not correct. It takes the last output '5' and add it to all the rows in the dataframe.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to add the output to the existing dataframe. Keep in mind my dataframe is much larger than this, there is about 4000 rows so I can't hardcode it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `lev_distance_a_b` only stores the last value of the computations. Just do:

```
df["a_b"] = [lev.distance(i, k) for i,k in zip(a, b)]
```